# Segmentation fault Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have just done sudo apt-get install firefox. Now when when I run the command firefox i get the error Segmentation Fault. Why is this , how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you running an headless server? Firefox is a graphical application therefore it needs a graphical environment.

Comment: No, I am running a gui Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Well, then Ubuntu 14.04 desktop already comes with Firefox, why exactly are you installing it? If you're trying to troubleshoot Firefox please describe the problem itself. Also whenever posting questions avoid being vague; if there are error messages make sure to copy/paste the entire messages.

Comment: I had to update the version of firefox due to my job. So i made this script:          #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                   sudo apt-get -y purge firefox                                                                                      sudo apt-get install firefox                                                                                       
This script was supposed to update firefox. After I run it I do the command to launch firefox, which is firefox. This returns the error Segmentation fault.

Comment: Well... No! That script merely uninstalls and reinstalls the exact same version. It should work anyway though if it was working before. If not, reinstalling isn't and wasn't likely to be the solution. And all that should be [edit]ed in the question and, whilst at that, try improving it by describing the actual problem and post all error messages, "segmentation fault" is meaningless.